# Failed to sync Gradle Project "Application name"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ide, android-gradle-plugin

**I installed Android Studio Today,When I Create New Project,the Gradle failed to sync project,(Android Studio 1.2 (JDK 1.7), Windows)**

Error:Unable to find method 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
 I did the above two steps, it doesn't work,When I Click Redownload dependencies,nothing happened(With Internet Connection)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.  

buildscript {  
repositories {  
    jcenter()  
}  
dependencies {  
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'  

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they  belong  
    // in the individual module build.gradle files  
}  
}  

 allprojects {  
 repositories {  
    jcenter()  
}  
}
```

Comment: can you please post the dependencies present in the build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

When I update my android studio, I got the same problem. Here is the solution I found: On the project tree "app", right click mouse button to get the context menu. Select "open module setting", on the tree "app" - "properties" tab, select the existing "build tools version". The gradle will start to build.